# Ошибочное добавление кнопок в vk_api

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, long-poll, python-keyboard

я пишу бота на Python, на Longpoll, появилась надобность в кнопках. Создал их, и среди них есть кнопки возвращение в меню. так, сделав круг (к примеру вернуться в меню > и снова вернуться в то место, где был) появляются ещё кнопки (см. скриншот), как мне удалять их? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
в коде я выделил места с проблемами

мой код:

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.keyboard import VkKeyboard, VkKeyboardColor
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType

keyboard = VkKeyboard(one_time=True)

token="Токен"
bh = vk_api.VkApi(token = token)
give = bh.get_api()
longpoll = VkLongPoll(bh)
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)
price = 0
skins=0
vk = vk_session.get_api()

def blasthack(id, text):
    bh.method('messages.send', {'user_id' : id, 'message' : text, 'random_id': 0})
print("Бот включен!")
for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
       if event.to_me:
          message = event.text.lower()
          id = event.user_id
          ids = event.user_id
          def GP(playerid, get): 
              user_get=give.users.get(user_ids = (playerid)) 
              user_get=user_get[0] 
              return user_get[get]
          def op():
            GP(str(ids), 'first_name')
          blasthack("568118601", 'Пользователь [id' + str(ids) + '|' + GP(str(ids), 'first_name') + ' ' + GP(str(ids), 'last_name') + '] написал сообщение:\n' + '"' + message + '"')

          if message == 'заказать мод':
            blasthack(id, '''
       Все доступные функции  
    ⭐[Внешние изменения]⭐
1) Скины - 2₽ за штуку
2) Замена анимации(на существующую в игре) - 1₽ за штуку
3) Замена фона(на ваш/из любой версии) - 25₽ за штуку 
4) Замена загрузочного экрана(на ваш/из любой версии) - 25₽
5) Замена шрифта - 15₽
6) Изменить текст - 0.5₽ за строчку
7) Замена саундтрека(на ваш/из любой версии) - 5₽ за штуку
8) Заменить эффекты скина - 1,5₽ за штуку
9) Добавить свой скин в игру - 15₽ за штуку
10) Модель по вашему заказу - от 100₽ за штуку(цена зависит от сложности работы)''')

          elif message == '1':
       #vvvvvv проблема тут vvvvvvvv
              keyboard.add_button('+1 к cкинaм', color=VkKeyboardColor.POSITIVE)
              keyboard.add_button('+5 к cкинaм', color=VkKeyboardColor.POSITIVE)
              keyboard.add_button('+10 к cкинaм', color=VkKeyboardColor.POSITIVE)

              keyboard.add_line()
              keyboard.add_button('-1 к cкинaм', color=VkKeyboardColor.NEGATIVE)
              keyboard.add_button('-5 к cкинaм', color=VkKeyboardColor.NEGATIVE)
              keyboard.add_button('-10 к cкинaм', color=VkKeyboardColor.NEGATIVE)

              keyboard.add_line()
              keyboard.add_button('Вернуться в меню', color=VkKeyboardColor.PRIMARY)
              vk.messages.send(
              peer_id=str(ids),
              message='Введите количество скинов (по кнопкам).\n+1 cкинaм - добавить 1 скин к заказу\n+5 к cкинaм - добавить 5 скинов к заказу\n+10 к cкинaм - добавить 10 скинов к заказу.\nАналогично с минусами',
              keyboard=keyboard.get_keyboard(),
              random_id=0
              )
              
          elif message == 'myname':
              blasthack(id, f'Ваше имя: [id' + str(ids) + '|' + GP(str(ids), 'first_name') + ' ' + GP(str(ids), 'last_name') + ']')
              main(id)

          elif message == "+1 к cкинaм":
              price+=2
              skins+=1
         #vvvvvvv проблема тут vvvvvv
              keyboard.add_button('Вeрнyтьcя нaзaд', color=VkKeyboardColor.POSITIVE)
              keyboard.add_line()
              keyboard.add_button('Зaвepшить зaкaз', color=VkKeyboardColor.NEGATIVE)
              vk.messages.send(
              peer_id=str(ids),
              message="Добавлено 1 скина(ов). Всего: " + str(skins) + " скинов, на сумму: " + str(price) + "₽!",
              keyboard=keyboard.get_keyboard(),
              random_id=0
              )
          elif message == 'вeрнyтьcя нaзaд':
              blasthack(str(ids), '''
       Все доступные функции  
    ⭐[Внешние изменения]⭐
1) Скины - 2₽ за штуку
2) Замена анимации(на существующую в игре) - 1₽ за штуку
3) Замена фона(на ваш/из любой версии) - 25₽ за штуку 
4) Замена загрузочного экрана(на ваш/из любой версии) - 25₽
5) Замена шрифта - 15₽
6) Изменить текст - 0.5₽ за строчку
7) Замена саундтрека(на ваш/из любой версии) - 5₽ за штуку
8) Заменить эффекты скина - 1,5₽ за штуку
9) Добавить свой скин в игру - 15₽ за штуку
10) Модель по вашему заказу - от 100₽ за штуку(цена зависит от сложности работы)''')
          elif message == 'зaвepшить зaкaз':
              blackhack(str(ids), 'Завершить заказ? Сумма вашего заказа: ' + str(price) + "₽")
        #vvvvvv проблема тут vvvvvvvv
              keyboard.add_button('Дa, зaвeршить', color=VkKeyboardColor.POSITIVE)
              keyboard.add_button('Нет, oтмeнить', color=VkKeyboardColor.NEGATIVE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создание кнопок стоит вынести за главный цикл. То есть объявить глобально. Затем в методе .message вызывать ту 'константу' к которой присвоены кнопки которая требуется. Для подобной реализации чтоб не создавать кучу переменных хорошо подойдет dict или list у которых имеется возможность редактирования и добавления вложенных в них объектов.